# PC randomly freezes up (troubleshooting & help)

Tags: hard-drive, memory, cpu, motherboard

I bought my new PC around sometime in may 2015. Since the day I got it, regardless what OS I have installed or running, it keeps on freezing and then the only way to get it to work again is to hard restart it.

*I am 100% sure this is a hardware issue*, since, as I mentioned before, OS or applications I am running have no effect on this, because it's happening very often. It happens even when I am running a LiveCD of Ubuntu or other LiveCD supported Linux derivates and distros.

I tried almost all versions of Windows and Linux distros, but still, no victory over it.

I have a Prestigio PC, part number is *PSXA6100D8S1T7260N* .

**My PC has these internals:**

- 8GB of DDR3 RAM, DIMM
- 1TB of HDD
- GPU: AMD R7260X 2GB
- CPU: AMD CPU Desktop FX-Series X6 6100 (3.3/3.9GHz,14MB,95W,AM3+)
- Chipset: AMD 970/SB950
- Power source: 650W

(The entire specs list is here: http://datacomp.sk/prestigio-xtreme-fx-x6-6100-3-3g-r7260x-8gb-1600hx-1tb-dvdrw-cr-hdmi-usb3-klv-mys-bez-os_d263877.html#.VmSPB3qVvCJ
Even though it's in Slovak language, you can understand it, I hope.)

If you'll need more info about my PC, feel free to ask, please.

I am guessing it may be a RAM issue but I am not sure. Since I have limited resources I do not want to buy a component that has a problem just out of my guess and then discover that the issue wasn't there. So, if you can help me to troubleshoot this and point at the component that I have to replace, I would be really grateful.

*Freezings are random, they do not happen at any given operation or usage.*

Thank you.

P.S.: The company from where I bought my PC is not responding me to e-mails I wrote them about the issue. So, making a reclamation and RMA is not an option here.)

Comment: You can test your RAM with Memtest86, but if the RAM was faulty you'd probably have your PC crash instead of freeze. Have you tested the HDD? Have you ever noticed if the CPU utilization abnormally high?

Comment: Hi DrZoo, I ran Memtest86 and it didn't show any problem, though. I haven't tested my HDD, how should I do it? The CPU utilization is normal I would say, may be a little bit too high, but just a little bit. When doing something 'heavy' then yes, it goes up like crazy.

Comment: But it can still freeze even when the CPU is at idle, right?

Comment: I'll say it this way: it can freeze even on the booting up phase, it can freeze when doing nothing just looking at the desktop or when having the PC in sleep mode or when looking a youtube video or even when doing heavy stuff like photoshop or Sony Vegas Pro...

Comment: I would check the HDD for bad sectors and see what results come back on that. You could try resetting the BIOS to default settings. After that, I'd start to think it may be motherboard related. You could also try and reseat your CPU to make sure everything is tight and secure.

Answer (score 1):

As @DrZoo suggests, it very well could be RAM... but also check in BIOS to see if there are changes that have been made in settings. The web site states it uses ASUS UEFI BIOS, so you might need to revert timing, interrupts etc. according to [ASUS suggestions](http://rog.asus.com/129672012/maximus-motherboards/asus-z77-motherboard-uefi-bios-tuning-guide/2/). Pay particular attention to the settings that might have been optimized for gaming, but should be better left at defaults.

One other possibility is a faulty power supply that occasionally "glitches". If you can, swap another ower supply and see if the issue goes away.

Also check any optimizations made to the video car settings -- sometimes changing the driver version helps (I've had the latest "upgrade" of video drivers causing crashes).

Comment: Hi @DrMoishe Pippik,
I didn't tune or overclock any of my PC's components.
I changed a few settings in BIOS but that didn't affect the PC's performance since this issue was happening since the day one.. 
I do not know if I will be able to provide myself an another power supply, but I will try. Thank you.

Comment: Even if *you* did not change BIOS settings, it might be worthwhile to confirm that the *manufacturer* did not change them.

Comment: Well, I did a restore defaults process, so I guess the BIOS is set up as it was meant to be.